# The grant type was not specified in the request in Toodledo API

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, authorization, access-token

I am using Toodledo API for my application. When following the steps to get the access token I got an error saying "The grant type was not specified in the request". 
First I need to get an authorization_code and I got using the following URI.

```
https://api.toodledo.com/3/account/authorize.php?response_type=code&client_id=toodleTest&state=mkop&scope=basic
```

And it returned a code for me. As the next step, I need to request the access token by using the following url.

```
https://api.toodledo.com/3/account/token.php
```

I have provided the URI parameters as grant_type and code. For the grant_type I gave "authorization_code" as mentioned in the API documentation. and aslo I have given the Authorization header as mentioned. But still it returns the above error without responsing with the access token.

Can someone please help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this.I have mistakenly given my login credentials other than the Client ID and Client secret.